# java Thread class run() method

Tags: java, multithreading

Thread class has run method to implement the business logic that could be executed in parallel.But I want implement different business logics in a single run method and to run simultaneously.How to get this feature.

thanks

Comment: Sounds like you want two threads... Can you add more details to your question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that the best course of action would be to have two separate threads.

You can (and probably should) write a new class that implements `Runnable` and inside it place your logic.
If there are common activities between the two business logics that you have to implement, you can use this class as a base class for the two "Runnables".
Each `Runnable` should be spawned in a separate thread.

You can find very good reasoning for `Thread vs. Runnable` on this post:
["implements Runnable" vs. "extends Thread"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/541487/java-implements-runnable-vs-extends-thread)

Answer (score 3):

That's right. You implement (or override) the `run`-method of a Thread to do stuff in parallell, however, there is an **important difference when calling `run` vs calling `start`**.

There is nothing special with the `run` method. Calling `run` will behave just like any call to a regular method, and the control will not return to the caller until the `run` method has finished. The magic happens in `start`. When calling `start` the control is returned to the calling side immediately, and a new thread is spawned that has the `run` method as entry point.

So, for example, if you want to execute two tasks simultaneously in different threads, you do something like:

```
Thread t = new Thread() {
    public void run() {
        doTask1();
    }
};

// Spawn a new thread that doTask1. (don't call run here!)
t.start();
// Control returns immediately while thread t is busy with doTask1.

doTask2();
```

An example run:

```
    Thread t = new Thread() { 
        public void run() {
            try {
                Thread.sleep(1000);
                System.out.println("Slept for 1 second.");
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            }
        }
    };

    t.run();
    System.out.println("Returned from run.");

    t.start();
    System.out.println("Returned from start.");
```

Yields output

```
                       (one second pause)
Slept for 1 second.
Returned from run.
Returned from start.
                       (one second pause)
Slept for 1 second.
```

Answer (score 0):

Make this run method spawn new thread with one logic and another thread with the second logic.